# Excel AddIn: How to duplicate one row multiple times, without breaking the replication of formulas and formats?

Tags: excel, automation, office-interop, excel-interop

I inherited a rather large worksheet and the fundamental task of my application is to insert a variable number of rows in it. Notice the empty template below:

[image: See Temmplate Here]

As you can see, the original designer decided that the minimum number of preconfigured rows should be TWO. This design decision probably makes sense in an interactive environment. Let's say we need 3 rows. In order not to break anything one row is added between rows 15 and 16.  Row 18 is shifted down but must importantly, its contents are updated accordingly.

I am working on a new, simplified template and am trying to keep only one preconfigured row (15). Row 16 (preconfigured Item No. 2) was removed from the template. This is what happens at run time: All additional rows under it are fine BUT the row with the totals (18) is not updated.

Perhaps the empty row (17) breaks the continuity and Excel gets lost?

Is this "sandwich" style required for a template?

TIA

Addendum: The formula in cell J18 is: =SUM(J15:J16). With the *sandwich* approach, the second argument becomes J17, J18, J19, J20, ... as my app adds new rows.

Comment: The problem is probably the AddIn which wasn't developed with this scenario taken into account. If you provide the formulas of column 18 we would be able to help better.

Comment: Thanks, Mikael: The formulas in row 18 are simple SUM() of the cells above it. I have a coworker who is an expert at using Excel interactively and he tells me that there must be two rows as a minimum. I said: "Perhaps there is a way to do it programmatically". I got no answers in the Microsoft forum, either. I will repost this question with code and formulas.

Comment: I added the relevant formula, Mikael. I seem to recall that if the sum goes to J17, the behavior will be different?

Comment: Row 18 will always give an error if the cell references it has contain an error. So Total Price at row 15 being an error is a problem as is row 16. Also the empty row does not matter as SUM() treats blank as 0.